# Not receiving android to iOS push notification and vice_versa using Pubnub

Tags: android, ios, notifications, pubnub

I am trying to send push notification from Android to iOS but failed to get notification on iOS device for each chat message. Android to Android push notification is working however, Android to iOS push notification is not working.

```
Below is the format of payload which is send for receiving push notification on Android and iOS:
{
  "uuid": "d587abbf-91f6-4231-a917-e42b9ecfc78a",
  "date": "2017-04-03T16:33:37.832+0530",
  "id": "8c6df2eb-44f8-4337-b66f-450749ec0dee",
  "stageName": "Vicky",
  "message": "jggiviib",
  "type": "chat",
  "status": 1,
  "pn_gcm": {
    "data": {
      "alert": "jggiviib",
      "type": "chat",
      "id": "8c6df2eb-44f8-4337-b66f-450749ec0dee",
      "stageName": "Vicky",
      "uuid": "d587abbf-91f6-4231-a917-e42b9ecfc78a",
      "message": "jggiviib",
      "date": "2017-04-03T16:33:37.832+0530"
    }
  },
  "pn_apns": {
    "aps": {
      "alert": "Vicky: jggiviib",
      "badge": 1,
      "data": {
        "type": "chat",
        "id": "8c6df2eb-44f8-4337-b66f-450749ec0dee",
        "stageName": "Vicky",
        "uuid": "d587abbf-91f6-4231-a917-e42b9ecfc78a",
        "message": "jggiviib",
        "date": "2017-04-03T16:33:37.832+0530"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am receiving push notification successfully for Android to Android. Similarly, iOS to iOS push notification is also working great.

Below is the method which registers channel for push notification:

```
public void addChannels() {
    pubnub.addPushNotificationsOnChannels().pushType(PNPushType.GCM)
            .channels(newChannels).deviceId(mLocalDataSource.getGcmToken()).async(new PNCallback<PNPushAddChannelResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(PNPushAddChannelResult result, PNStatus status) {
            if (status.isError()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "enable push notifications failed");
                status.retry();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "registered for push notifications successfully");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And the method for sending message:

```
public void sendMessage(final ChatMessage chatMessage) {
    JsonObject jsonSend = chatMessage.toJson();
    jsonSend.add("pn_gcm",chatMessage.toGcmPlayload());
    jsonSend.add("pn_apns", chatMessage.toAPNPayload());

    Log.d(TAG,"apns payload :" +chatMessage.toAPNPayload());
    pubnub.publish().message(jsonSend).channel(chatMessage.mChatChannel.getChannelName())
            .shouldStore(true)
            .async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(PNPublishResult result, PNStatus status) {
                    if (status.isError()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "error occurred");
                        status.retry();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "published successfully");
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

I have also followed troubleshooting guide of Pubnub and during debugging using Pubnub console, the devices registered for APNS shows 0.

```
 "Devices found for push notification apns: 0 gcm: 2 mpns: 0"
```

Comment: I provided response in the support ticket you sent to us. We will respond here with final answer.

Comment: We responded with a link to a guide to help troubleshoot your issue but we never heard back from you whether that helped resolve or not. Please let us know if you still have issues.